# How to instantiate a class function for not instantiated objects?

Tags: python, function, instance

Does anyone know if there is a way to instantiate a function of a class for not yet instantiated objects in Python? I would like something like this:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def f1(self):
        self.var += 1
    def f2(self):
        self.var += 2

cond = True
if cond : f = C.f1
else:     f = C.f2

for i in xrange(1e7):
    a = C(1)
    for j in xrange(1e3):
        a.f()
```

The goal is to be able to use 'f' as 'min', 'max' or 'mean' for nparrays at the beginning and not checking at each loops which function to use.

Comment: `f = rand().min` and then `f(a)`?

Comment: It can't work because `rand()` returns a scalar.
`f = a.min` and then `f()` could work but in my case `a` can change.

Comment: Never used `pylab` so i commented on a hunch, ignore my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types of `a` and `b` are `numpy.ndarray`. You have imported `ndarray`, so you can simply call `ndarray.min` on `a` and `b`:

```
f = ndarray.min
print f(a), f(b)
```

Here, `ndarray.min(x)` is equivalent to `x.min()`.

**Edit** getting the `numpy.ndarray.min` without explicit knowledge of the type of a call to `rand`:

```
f = type(rand(int())).min
```

Note that you still need to know that this type has a `min` function.

Comment: But how to do when ndarray.min does not exist ? If class `C` have different functions `f1`, `f2` and `a` is not yet instantiated as `C` object how to write `f` as `C.f1` or `C.f2` ?

Comment: @Gmoaltos perhaps you can illustrate that with an example, because I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, how to answer with well formated code and not everything in one line ?

Comment: @Gmoaltos you can edit your question and add an illustrative example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's seems to work with rand (and thank you) but doesn't work with my class `C` for exemple. Do you know from where comes the problem ?

Comment: @Gmoaltos You have to call `f(a)`, not `a.f()`.

Answer (score 0):

One does not "instantiate" a function; one instantiates objects, as instances of classes.

Now, one simply calls a class method of a class `klass` by calling the method on the class: `klass.method(foo)`.

If `rand.min` is a function which can be called on `a`, then one would simply do `rand.min(a)` or `f(a)`.

Comment: I didn't really understand. Usually you do `a.min()` and you can't do `y=rand.min`

Comment: @Gmoaltos What do you mean "usually"?

Comment: No it's ok sorry. I get it. Thank you